# Charting average sales per weekday on data composed of hours

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

I'm using PowerBI desktop and I'm creating a chart to display **average sales per weekday**:

[image]

My data is in the format below:

*(sampled in Excel to remove sensitive information, added colors to facilitate visualization)*

[image: sample_data]

**My problem is**: since each day is broken in 24 rows (hours), my average is wrong by a factor of 24.

For example, if I select January-2019 in the slicer, which has five Tuesdays (weekday code: 2), I want to see on the bar number 2:

- **(sum of amount where weekday = 2) / 5**

Instead, I'm calculating:

- **(sum of amount where weekday = 2) / (24 * 5)**

---

I can think of some ways to get this right, but they involve custom columns or auxiliary tables. I'm sure there is a simpler answer using DAX and measures, but I'm still learning it.

How can I correctly calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your table name is "Data". Create 3 DAX **measures** (not calculated columns):

Measure 1:

```
Total Amount = SUM(Data[Amount])
```

Measure 2:

```
Number of Days = DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[Date])
```

Measure 3:

```
Average Amount per Day = DIVIDE( [Total Amount], [Number of Days])
```

Drop the last measure into a chart, it should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your excel you are working with 3 different columns. You can better combine this to a datetime and let power-bi handle it.

Below m-language will do this for you:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\....\Test.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"date", type datetime}, {"hour", type time}, {"amount", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each  [date]+ Duration.FromText(Time.ToText([hour]))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"amount", "Date"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each ([amount] <> 0))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

The trick is in the added column: #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each  [date]+ Duration.FromText(Time.ToText([hour])))

Here I add the time to the date.

I also removed the empty (zero amount) rows, you do not need them.

[image]

I added the Date & weekday to the Axis so a user can now drill down from year, month, day to weekday.
Be aware you need to do the SUM of the amount, not the average.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Aldert. How can you plot by weekday when you have "Date" and "weekday" on the axis? I tried, but it plots by date (year, quarter, month or day, whatever is on the hierarchy). Hourly amounts are a core part of my system, but I do believe your suggestion to merge date and time can simplify the making of the dashboard and also improve performance.

Comment: It will drill down to weekdays (done by user for sure). If you do not need it you can have only weekday on axis..